# Assinatura digital de XML com certificado A1

Tags: php

Preciso assinar digitalmente um XML com certificado digital do tipo A1 para uma tarefa de NFSe.

Não tenho experiência no assunto e encontrei muito pouco na Web. Alguém que já tenha desenvolvido com alguma indicação de como proceder ou com a sequencia de passos a serem executados?

Não quero código pronto, somente um caminho ou exemplos de como proceder.

Comment: queria saber também